# How to create a function and make it globally available for formatting datetime in laravel 5

Tags: php, function, datetime, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I am working on a project with a lots of datetime values that would be display on the UI. In Code Igniter I use to create a function like below and put in a helper directory and make available in my app.

```
function datetime_to_text($datetime){
    return date('j F Y, g:i a', strtotime($datetime));
}
```

How can I make such a function available globally in laravel 5 (Able to access in both my views and controllers)

Comment: Have you seen `http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators` and `https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datetimes in Laravel are converted to `Carbon` objects.

Carbon is a **wonderful** library.

By default, `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `deleted_at` are automatically converted for you. If you have other DATETIME columns in your table, you simply need to add them to the `$dates` array in your Eloquent model:

```
class User {
    protected $dates = ['logged_in_at'];
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Now when you echo `$object->created_at`, it calls the Carbon `__toString()` method. You can set a default format with:

```
Carbon::setToStringFormat('j F Y, g:i a');
```

Or you can easily format things with

```
echo $object->created_at->format('j F Y, g:i a');
```

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: Thanks @andrewtweber. Where should I put Carbon::setToStringFormat('j F Y, g:i a'); so I don't have to do $object->created_at->format('j F Y, g:i a'); every time. I am using blade for my views.

Comment: My goal is to have a single place where I can change the format of my datetime. Carbon::setToStringFormat('j F Y, g:i a'); is what I really want but I don't know where to set this. I have put it in my models but keep getting error. I have put in my view but not working either. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @FokwaBest try putting it in your app service provider. `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` I think is the file. That's a good place to put global "boot up" things

Comment: You can set `protected $dateFormat = 'j F Y, g:i a';` within your model to set a date format that should be used by Carbon.

Comment: @Tim correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that's the format it's stored in in the database, not how it's outputted as `__toString`. Or is it both?

Answer (score -1):

**It's maybe helpful for CodeIgniter experts:**

You can create a file in `app/Helpers/` (with making `Helpers` directory)

like: `app/Helpers/`**HelperClass.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class HelperClass{

    public static function updatedOn($updated_at)
    {
        return 'Last updated '. $updated_at->diffForHumans();
    }
}
```

Now you've to add this `HelperClass` in `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
   ...,
   'HelperClass' => 'App\Libraries\HelperClass'
]
```

Now just call in your view page:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   {!! HelperClass::updatedOn($data->updated_at) !!}
</div>
```

Output like: `Last updated 5 minutes ago.`

Comment: This is interesting. I will experiment this technique and see what I get.

Comment: Thank you so much AnowarCst. Both you and @andrewtweber answers have given me incredible insight. I am using both techniques in my project right now.

Comment: That's great :) , carry on @FokwaBest